# How to execute my python library at the cmd like auto-py-to-exe

Tags: python, python-module, auto-py-to-exe

I recently created my first python module, it is a program that can convert more than one python file to `exe` at the same time using multiprocessing (https://github.com/Lima-49/Multiples_Exe)

But I want to execute this module like auto-py-to-exe library, just typing this command at the cmd

How can I do this ?

Comment: you need to asd the .py file to your path directory, or move it to the folder where the rest of your downloaded modules are stored

Comment: @ChristianTrujillo i didn't understand your advice, i must put my source code at the main folder ? Could you please explicate more ?

Comment: If im being fully honest, I cant go into too much detail cause I dont have the best grasp on it either lol, but your Path directory is (to my knowledge) where your computer checks when told to look for python modules, to add to it you can follow this guide https://gist.github.com/nex3/c395b2f8fd4b02068be37c961301caa7. otherwise, you can find where the rest of your python modules were downloaded to, for me its C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Lib\site-packages, and move your .py script there, after you should be able to call it from your command prompt